# Is there an error in Rado's proof of the Canonical Ramsey Theorem?

Tags: co.combinatorics

I am having trouble understanding the paper with the URL: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/TOPICS/canramsey/Rado.pdf

I get stuck around the middle of page 2 where it says: 
$f(z_0, \dots, z_{r-1}) = f(y_0, \dots, y_{r-1})$

This assertion doesn't seem to follow from the quantifiers defining $L$. 
I do see that there exists *some* $y_0$, $y_1$,... and *some* $y_0'$, $y_1'$, ... 
to make the above equality true but that's not enough because here the $y_i$ and $y_i'$ are arbitrary.

We are given that $\rho_0$ does not belong to $L$. However, $L$ is defined by a "for all" statement. So for $\rho_0$, the for-all statement is false and we can find some $y_i$ and $y_i'$ to make $f(z_0, \dots, z_{r-1}) = f(y_0, \dots, y_{r-1})$ true.

But the author is stating something much stronger -- that we can deduce the equality for an arbitrary $y_i$ and $y_i'$.

Many thanks for any help or insights.

Paul Epstein

Answer (score 4):

I think you're overlooking the fact that $g$, defined at the top of page 2, is constant on $[B']^{2r}$ (and therefore on $[B]^{2r}$).  This means that, as long as the $y_i, y'_i, z_i$ and $z_i'$ are drawn from $B'$, equality of $f$-values at any two of these  $r$-tuples depends only on the relative sizes of the $2r$ numbers in those two $r$-tuples. So one can indeed go from information about some two $r$-tuples to information about every pair of "similarly configured" $r$-tuples.